# How to modify/prefix woocommerce order number before API send? Modified order number not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the WooCommerce order number (ID?) to get a prefix and after that get a logistics plugin to send this modified order ID via an API.

If I do this - as it was in every solution regarding modified order number - it changes the order number everywhere (admin, mails, etc.) but the 3rd party plugin sends the default postID via the API somehow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'add_woocommerce_order_number_prefix' );
function add_woocommerce_order_number_prefix( $order_id ) {
    $prefix = 'CZ-';
    return $prefix . $order_id;
}
```

I checked the code of the 3rd party plugin, and it sends a JSON array based on this structure:

```
return array(

  'status'                    => $status,

  'order_id'                  => $order_id,

  'order_name'                => $order_id,

  'created_at'                => $order->order_date,
.
.
.
etc.
```

It hooks to every possible WooCommerce order status change action and executes a function to send data.

Is there a solution/hooking/etc. where I can modify this $order_id in such a way, that before this plugin executes, it sends the modified ID afterwards? I'm afraid that maybe I need to change the ID before the plugin in WooCommerce somehow (if it is even possible) OR hardcode the prefixing into the 3rd party plugin (which would not be a good solution).

Thanks!

Comment: We don't know where that 3rd party plugin _gets_ its `$order_id` from. Just because it uses the same variable _name_, does not mean it refers to the same data. You will have to figure out where this is _set_ within the plugin scope first of all.

Comment: It uses this:
`// construct WC_Order.
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);`
  
Then:
`function GetOrderData($order, $status)
{
$order_id = $order->id;`

Comment: That is how `$order` is created, not `$order_id`, which the shown plugin code accesses.

Comment: I think you have a catch-22 situation here. `$order = new WC_Order($order_id);` - at this point, I am guessing that `$order_id` must contain the unmodified order ID - otherwise, I doubt that this would _find_ the correct order to begin with.

Comment: The plugin code continuously referring to this $order_id variable, not creating it. Thats why I think that it is the same as the WooCommerce variable. But maybe I'm wrong.
What you are saying means that If I want it to send a modified order number, I must modify the plugin code itself?  I haven't found any hooks that can modify the order number before it is created, and even then WC uses a default post ID... so...

Comment: I am pretty sure that this hook only modifies the order number for the runtime of the PHP code, but does not change it in the database. (The id there is a numeric field, so adding a prefix like `CZ-` in the database would not even be possible.) And that in turn means, that `new WC_Order($order_id)` needs to be using the original, unmodified order id, otherwise this would not find the record in the database. But if `$order_id` is the original, unmodified order id - then you can't expect `'order_id' => $order_id,` to result in the modified one.

Comment: Maybe this part? @param int $order_id

Comment: `@param int $order_id` - that annotation already states that this value should be an integer - so operating with any values prefixed with `CZ-` at this point, would likely not work to begin with, or lead to trouble somewhere else later. I think you should probably contact the provider of your plugin, and ask them to make the necessary modifications to correctly take the modification of the order number via that hook into account at this point.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the info, I will check these out once more and contact them.